# Contract "true", such that "assert true x==x" holds

Tags: haskell, contract

Is it possible to write a contract that checks whether a statement is true? 
For example, I want to define a contract

```
true :: Contract a
```

such that for all values x, the equation

```
assert true x == x
```

holds.

I have tried something like this:

```
true :: Contract a
true = Pred (\a -> True)
```

But when running `assert true x == x` compiler says that `x` is undefined. 
When running  `assert true 5==6` the result is  `False`, and I have hoped for a  `Contract violation error`.
How should I change this  `true` contract? Would appreciate your help.

Here

```
data Contract :: * -> * where
  Pred :: (a -> Bool) -> Contract a
  Fun  :: Contract a -> Contract b -> Contract (a -> b)
```

Assert will cause a run-time failure if a contract is violated, and otherwise return the original result:

```
assert :: Contract a -> a -> a
assert (Pred p)       x = if p x then x else error "contract violation"
assert (Fun pre post) f = assert post . f . assert pre
```

Comment: I assume this is using a library. Could you specify which library you are using?

Comment: @bradrn I don't. I define the Contract type and assert function myself

Comment: Then could you provide us with the definitions? We can’t help you unless we know what you’re using.

Comment: @bradrn I did. After the word "Here", at the end of the question. (I edited the question)

Comment: Oh, sorry! I completely missed those definitions!  (And @RobinZigmond, they were there when I first commented — I just didn’t notice them.) Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Side note: Haskell has plenty of expressions, not so many statements (the report describes `import` and entries in `do` as statements).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see the problem very clearly if you consider your definitions of `true` and `assert`. Here are the relevant parts:

```
true :: Contract a
true = Pred (\a -> True) 

assert :: Contract a -> a -> a
assert (Pred p)       x = if p x then x else error "contract violation"
...
```

Put them together and you see that `assert true x` will test `(\a -> True) x` and either produce `x` or throw an error, depending on if it's `True` or `False`. And that this will always be `True`, no matter what expression you use for `x`, since the predicate by definition always returns `True`, and ignores its argument.

The simple fix is to have the `true` "contract" actually test its argument, like this:

```
true :: Contract Bool
true = Pred id
```

That is, this new `true` can only apply to a value of type `Bool` (because it really doesn't make sense for any others) and does nothing to it. It lets the value through unchanged if it's `True`, and otherwise throws the contract violation error you want:

```
Prelude> assert true (5==6)
*** Exception: contract violation
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:21:46 in interactive:Ghci2
Prelude> assert true (5==5)
True
```

And note the parentheses in `assert true (5==6)`, since `assert true 5==6` is parsed as `(assert true 5)==6`, due to function application being the most precedent "operator" in Haskell. `assert true 5==6` leads to an error because this corrected version of `true` only works on a Boolean value, and therefore not on `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `assert true x == x` compares `assert true x` to `x`; so `assert true 5` is `5` and of course `5 == 6` is false and not a contract violation.

If you intended `assert true (x == x)` to hold instead, then it seems like

```
true :: Contract Bool
true = Pred id

assert true (5==6)  -- Contract violation
```

is what you want

Answer (score 0):

"when running assert true x == x compiler says that x is undefined" is rather key here. Your `assert` call appears to me to be one expression containing two references to `x`, and the outermost function is `(==)`. Neither side can be evaluated without a binding for `x`. The `assert true x` portion never sees `==`, and if we rewrote it to `assert true (x == x)` we'd still need to provide an `x :: Eq a`. I don't know how to examine a function as such, but there certainly are options I'm not well versed in.